# Is there a ready to go (boilerplate) project to make request/rpcs to my daedalus (cardano-node)?

Tags: graphql-engine, docker

Since [cardano-rest](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-rest) is deprecated not sure if [cardano-graphql](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql) is the way to go just to get data from the blockchain. It seems like the setup to start with is very complex for newbies.

I've never used Docker or Graphql, but I have nodejs/JavaScript/JSON/HTTP/RPC skills. What is the lightest set-up to communicate with the Cardano blockchain?

Answer (score 3):

You can use dandeliona APIs as available [here](https://gimbalabs.com/dandelionapis/graphql-api) provided by Gimbalabs or [BlackFrost](https://blockfrost.io/) in case you wanted hosted services. Running docker image for Cardano-graphql is not that involved.

Comment: It is if you don't have docker installed. Plus is getting complicated when you start getting errors like this one: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/issues/508